# Waiting for Debugger message stuck when debug app

Tags: android, debugging

I debug my app send it show Waiting for Debugger Dialog and It does not disappear. I have answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27436050/5241603), but it not work. Restart IDE and device not work for me. Look at this:

[image: .]

This is info from my log

```
11-28 13:28:35.345 7717-7717/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-28 13:28:35.396 7717-7717/? W/ActivityThread: Application xx.com.xxx.xxxx is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-28 13:28:35.398 7717-7717/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

                                             [ 11-28 13:28:35.430  1581: 1602 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fde038e9480, tid 1602
```

### UPDATE

It said:

`Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable android ndk and ndk workspace support in file->setting->plugins

Comment: Short Answer, Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app and rebuild.